# googlemock framework doesn't work with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, googletest, multiple-inheritance, googlemock, virtual-inheritance

It looks like I can not use virtual inheritance when trying to mock interfaces. I need to use virtual inheritance because my code depends on a third-party library. The 3rd-party library uses virtual inheritance to cast from one child to another, through the parent. We need to be able to mock according to the expectations of the 3rd-party library, but this is not the case.

Note: IA, IB, IC, and ID are a 3rd party library

```
class IA
{
};

class IB :virtual public IA
{
};

class IC :virtual public IB
{
public:
    int getValue(){}
};

class ID : virtual public IA
{ 
public:
    void type(){};
};

class MockD :
              public ID 
    //virtual public ID; fails all of my tests that depends on ID
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(type, void())
}; 

class MockC :
    //virtual public IC, virtual public MockD{}; //throws an exception for accessing pD->type()
    //        public IC, virtual public MockD{}; //throws an exception for accessing pD->type()
    //virtual public IC,         public MockD{}; //throws an exception for accessing pC->getValue()
    //        public IC,         public MockD{}; //throws an exception for accessing pD->type() 
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(getValue, void());

};
```

```
//throws an exception for accessing pD->type()


           IA
        _______
    (v)/       \(v)
      IB        ID
   (v)|         |
     IC       MockD
      |         |
    (v)\        /(v)   
         MockC


           IA
        _______
    (v)/       \(v)
      IB        ID
   (v)|         |
     IC       MockD
      |         |
      \        /(v)   
         MockC           


           IA
        _______
    (v)/       \(v)
      IB        ID
   (v)|         |
     IC       MockD
      |         |
      \        /   
         MockC           

//throws an exception for accessing pC->getValue()

           IA
        _______
    (v)/       \(v)
      IB        ID
   (v)|         |
     IC       MockD
      |         |
   (v)\        /   
         MockC           
           IA
```

Code to be tested

```
ID* pD = dynamic_cast<ID*>(pC);
pD->type();
pC->getValue();
```

// in the test

```
MockC* mockC = new MockC();
EXPECT_CALL(mockC, type());
EXPECT_CALL(mockC, getValue());
```

Comment: Interface classes used as virtual base classes usually are polymorphic

Answer (score 0):

You just want Mock object that derives from `ID` and mock all its functions. Then forget about `MockC` and just define `MockD` in a way you need:

```
class MockD : public ID 
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(type, void());
    MOCK_METHOD0(getValue, int());
};
```

And setup your test expectation in this way:

```
MockD mockD;
EXPECT_CALL(mockD, type());
EXPECT_CALL(mockD, getValue()).WillOnce(Return(0)); //not sure you want zero - use return value that you needs
```

Then - assuming this is `void codeUnderTest(IC& c)` - the code you want to test - just pass `mockD` to this code:

```
codeUnderTest(mockD);
```

---

In case you need both `MockD` and `MockC` for some other reasons - then use template definitions to achieve this goal:

```
template <typename Interface>
class MockCT : public Interface
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(getValue, int());
};
using MockC = MockCT<IC>;

template <typename Interface>
class MockDT : public MockCT<Interface>
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(type, void());
};
using MockD = MockDT<ID>;
```